# How to obtain NFCEE_ADMIN permission on rooted phone?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, rooted-device

The NFCEE_ADMIN permission is signature level.
However, is it possible to "cheat" to get this permission on a rooted phone ? Maybe using a technique similar to [the way ClockSync does it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739074/setting-system-time-of-rooted-phone) ?

I am trying to use reflexion techniques to get access to NFCExtras :

```
mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

try {
    Class mynfcextras = Class.forName("android.nfc.INfcAdapterExtras");
    Method getnfcExtras = mAdapter.getClass().getMethod("getNfcAdapterExtrasInterface");
    Object nfcExtras = getnfcExtras.invoke(mAdapter);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But of course get the following error : "NFCEE_ADMIN permission required: Neither user xxx nor current process has com.android.nfc.permission.NFCEE_ADMIN."

Edit : Of course, I did add the permission to the package, but it is removed during installation :

```
W/PackageManager(  XXX): Not granting permission com.android.nfc.permission.NFCEE_ADMIN to package XXX (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x8be46)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of your app needs to be in `/system/etc/nfcee_access.xml`. See e.g. http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/wiki/BuildingTheSystem for an example how to create it.

Comment: Is the only solution to build my own image ? I was trying to avoid this :/
I don't quite understand this sentence : "This file claims to include signatures of applications that can retrieve the NFCEE_ADMIN permission. However, it seems to be the signer certificate chain instead of the application signature."

Comment: OK. Managed to get the application signature into the nfcee_access.xml file. But it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Ok. The nfcee_access.xml is only used for users build, not production ones. I used CM9, works like a charm.