# Android - NFC reading and writing locally

Tags: android, nfc

Is there a way to read/write data to a local NFC chip? I know that you can read/write data to/from a scanned NFC tag but I couldn't find any samples how to target a local NFC chip.

Moreover, does anybody know how to get the tag id of local NFC hardware?

Comment: Do you mean by "local NFC chip" the embedded Secure Element?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment it is not possible to access the embedded Secure Element("NFC chip") on a commercial device. If you root your phone as explained here [How to obtain NFCEE_ADMIN permission on rooted phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545734/how-to-obtain-nfcee-admin-permission-on-rooted-phone) you can get access to it. But this will not help u a lot, since in order to load new applets on it you need the Issuer keys. When you get access to it you will be able to read the ID, but it can turn our that it is randomly generated so it will not help you a lot.

To summarize using the embedded SE will not bring you too much benefits. For the moment you can try with some alternative solutions as Micro SD cards or NFC-enabled SIM cards.