# How to change the date on android, programmatically?

Tags: android, date, time, root

### background

since it could be useful for testing of apps that need to run based on dates and time, it could be nice to create a widget/shortcut on the "desktop" of android, and by a single click to skip a few hours/days/...

### the problem

i don't think there is such a thing using the normal API. the only similar thing is to use an intent to open the date options.

### the question

is it possible to do it using the API of android? if not, is it possible to do it using ROOT? how?

---

EDIT: i've found a way to do it using root, [**here**](http://mrothouse.wordpress.com/2007/02/20/setting-datetime-on-unix/) , but i can't find the correct parameters and documentation of how to use it (the link isn't correct about the parameters for  android).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to root your device, just use following code,

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

The another way is by using [SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) class's setCurrentTimeMillis(long millis) method.

Comment: again, i already know that there is an intent for going to the settings. i've asked how i can change it myself, without letting the user going over the settings.

Comment: Yes, and how about another way ?

Comment: i don't think that a normal permission can be used for this. i've now found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8752130/878126 . not sure i understand how it works though, but it seems that root is required.