# How to change displayed time by OS on android?

Tags: android, datetime

I know that I can't change system time on android. But I need to modify time that dispays on screen clock (in the corner). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: No there is no way to alter the time displayed by the OS. You can changed the system time if the device is rooted though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739074/setting-system-time-of-rooted-phone

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to edit the system's/OS time programmatically.
However you can invoke the settings to open the date/time activity but the user has to change the time.

> startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));

Comment: No :( I need to change the time without letting user know. I thought that I can replace the time displayed by the OS with something else without invoking to system time

Answer (score -1):

Hei, you can set the new time in Android Programatically. See this Question on SO [Set Android Date/ Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332269/how-to-set-mobile-system-time-and-date-in-android) .
Don't forgot to use this: `startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));`