# Emulator's clock doesn't match the host system clock

Tags: android, android-emulator, clock, android-virtual-device

Why doesn't the Android emulator's clock match the host system clock?  It's **not a time zone difference**--it's always off by several minutes.

Is there a way to synchronize them besides manually setting the emulator's time?

Comment: Can you set the time via  the settings the same way you can on a device?

Comment: @Sam : Urrrm, if I understand the OP correctly, I think he means the 'Clock' as in the thing which shows the current time on the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation yet to post a comment on the asker's question, or else I would. When you launch your emulator through the Android AVD Manager, do you have save to snapshot or launch from snapshot enabled?

Comment: @Squonk Seems these "Clock things" are confusing, here's [a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/jBGmy.jpg) with the emulator's UTC (Universal Time) and my host system's time.

Comment: @Sam : I think you missed my point. The OP states "it's often off by several minutes." which clearly isn't a time-zone variation from UTC. You might create AVDs which default to UTC but I set mine to my own locale which means the AVD shows my time-zone and not UTC.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? I had exactly the same issue and I fixed it via a script I installed in my `crontab`. This can be easily done in MacOS (as I did) or in Linux systems.

Answer (score 62):

I had the same problem and got it resolved by just restarting the emulator using emulator power button.

Comment: I needed a Cold Boot from AVD manager but then this worked for me

Comment: you can use command `adb reboot`

Comment: I used " wipe data " using AVD manager and then did a " Cold Boot Now " and it worked!

Comment: Thanks @Balaramakrishna Rachumallu, Working for me after restart emulator

Answer (score 24):

I believe there is no way to synchronize the time. The default image of the emulator sets to UTC/GMT (+00:00). However you can change it to your own.

Here is an image on how to do so:
First un-check the "Automatic Time Zone" (red arrow) then click on the "Selected Time Zone" (green arrow) and finally select your time zone and it should match the one on your system (yellow arrow).
[image: timezone screen shots]

Comment: even if the minutes are off on  his  setup as he seems to indicate, it should  still  be possible to fix it this way by taking off automatic date&time  and manually setting both hours and minutes to whatever you please. Including whatever the system time is.

Comment: yes :) as you mentioned it would be possible to "synchronize" it by setting it manually.

Comment: I stated in the question that this is **not** a timezone problem, that it is off by several minutes (not hours).

Comment: This worked for me.  Although I admit, my issue was not exactly the same--just a timezone problem.

Comment: @JeffAxelrod: Apparently, your question got a life of its own, independent of your original intentions: People like me, who *do* have a timezone problem, get your question as the top Google result, get helped by the first answer and upvote it. I am tempted to modify your question to match the answers, but I would not want to do that without your consent.

Comment: @Heinzi LOL, no, I wasn't asking about how to synchronize time zones. So much so that I bolded the question to indicate that specifically.

Answer (score 12):

On AndroidTV API 28 simulator, this works (GNU/Linux, and some Mac) :

`adb shell su root date $(date +%m%d%H%M%Y.%S)`

The host timezone should match your AndroidTV timezone.

Comment: worked on my Mac m1

Comment: There's a fuller answer on how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10385337/120398

Answer (score 10):

The `date` command has changed in newer androids since the other answers. You must have root, `-s` is not recognized and the set format has changed.

I've had luck using `adb shell su root date -u @$(date +%s.%N)`, which uses `@` to set it using UNIX timestamp seconds with nanosecond precision. `-u` is required if you have changed the timezone for some reason, even though timestamps should not have a time zone!

Comment: Thank you. This is the only answer that has worked in recent times. For macOS, just skip the nanoseconds, so: `adb shell su root date -u @$(date +%s)`

Answer (score 9):

If there are some discrepancies between the AVD and host times, mainly after restarting from a snapshot you can use `adb shell date` to check and/or set the date just after you launched the emulator.

Comment: `adb shell date ` is a effective way though it can not solve the issue completely

Answer (score 5):

As I've got this as top link in google :)

On **windows** you can get right time by issuing

```
adb shell date -s %date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
```

`-s` value should be in format: `YYYYMMDD.hhmmss`

On systems that have **different time format**, portion with windows shell args **will be different!**

You can test out in `cmd.exe`:

```
> echo %date%
Thu 01/22/2015
```

To output YYYY part use: `%date:[position of char. 0-based],[length]%`

On **linux**:

```
adb shell date -s $(date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S)
```

Comment: on mac terminal: works only on emulator or rooted device.
adb shell su root "date $(date +%m%d%H%S)"

Comment: @Thupten on macOS your command gives me error `/system/bin/sh: su: not found`

Comment: @Thupten has a slight mistake, it should be: `adb shell su root "date $(date +%m%d%H%M)"`

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you need to put quote around the datetime string to avoid error when the parsing returns a space in front of a digit.

The complete syntax would be:

```
adb shell date -s '%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Mackbook Air M2 - Android Studio Flamingo-emulator API 33.Had the same issue.Cold reboot after setting time zone of emulator worked for me.

Comment: Linux (Fedora) had the same issue and solved by the same method.