# Cannot load API response in Android due to wrong date time in device with HTTPS URL

Tags: android, rest, ssl, https

When I call an API hosted on a secure server SSL (HTTPS) and the date time of the system are wrong (set manually) then we have following errors:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Response is unreliable: its validity interval is out-of-date
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Could not determine revocation status
```

Is there any way to allow application to load the response from an API even with wrong mobile date and time?

The strange issue is that all other apps are working fine even those that have APIs with HTTPS.

What changes I need to do so it allows mobile app to call the API (HTTPS) with wrong date time as well?

Comment: The same occurs in my app. One thing that I couldn't figured out though is that it only occurs on the first run of the app. If I close and reopen the app, even with the wrong date set on my device, the error stops happening.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem. The emulator device has a wrong date and https connections fail.
You can try to use some examotage.

When I had to solve this kind of problem I found that the simple solution is the best: simply change date time of the device.

To do this by shell commands, try these links on [medium](https://medium.com/@siwakornsittilerdpaisal/how-to-fix-the-wrong-date-of-androids-emulator-bc3ea13dfdb3), and on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148309/emulators-clock-doesnt-match-the-host-system-clock).

I hope it helps you.

Comment: This helps me, the Android S emulator on M1 device has wrong date. Reset the date by following the instruction on those link will fix the error CertPathValidatorException Response is unreliable its validity interval is out-of-date