# Date not updated when restoring snapshot

Tags: android, emulation, snapshot

When I start up the emulator that is set to save snapshot, the emulator still uses the date since I last ran it, which is 4 days ago. I'm trying to work on my app and I need to have this update so I can test things properly since my app uses a log with dates.

How do I fix this without losing all the data of the snapshot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emulated Android device does not re-sync time/date after restoring snapshot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916609/emulated-android-device-does-not-re-sync-time-date-after-restoring-snapshot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just had to go into Settings and disabled "automatic date" and just manually set the date for the OS.