# Date and Time of Android Studio Emulator does not sync when I turn on PC after hibernation

Tags: android, date, time, synchronization, emulation

I set the correct Date and Time in Emulator (of Android Studio). Then I hibernate my PC. Now when I start my PC after say one day, the emulator still shows the old date and time. This is causing problems for my chat application testing, and I have to set it every time.
"Set time automatically" also does not work. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: I have also started to notice this recently. Really annoying.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239451112?pli=1

Comment: There's an old related question about restoring from a snapsnot, but all the same advice is applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8916609/120398