# Integer expression expected error in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm a newbie to shell scripts so I have a question. What Im doing wrong in this code?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " Write in your age: "
read age
if [ "$age" -le "7"] -o [ "$age" -ge " 65" ]
then
echo " You can walk in for free "
elif [ "$age" -gt "7"] -a [ "$age" -lt "65"]
then
echo " You have to pay for ticket "
fi
```

When I'm trying to open this script it asks me for my age and then it says

```
./bilet.sh: line 6: [: 7]: integer expression expected
./bilet.sh: line 9: [: missing `]'
```

I don't have any idea what I'm doing wrong. If someone could tell me how to fix it I would be thankful, sorry for my poor English I hope you guys can understand me.

Comment: Aren't you normally supposed to have whitespace between a command's arguments? Why did you omit it?

Comment: [this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) explains a lot about the various bash comparison syntaxes.

Comment: Is it an integer or blank?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " Write in your age: "
read age

if [[ "$age" -le 7 || "$age" -ge 65 ]] ; then
    echo " You can walk in for free "
elif [[ "$age" -gt 7 && "$age" -lt 65 ]] ; then
    echo " You have to pay for ticket "
fi
```

Comment: And when I do that I get `test.sh: line 3: [[: 109 test: syntax error in expression (error token is "test")`

Comment: @BradenBest , others : I am having a similar problem with: <br/>

  while [ "$COUNTER+1" -lt "$array_length" ]; do
<br/>
It gives me:

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 16):

This error can also happen if the variable you are comparing has hidden characters that are not numbers/digits.

For example, if you are retrieving an integer from a third-party script, you must **ensure that the returned string does not contain [hidden characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), like `"\n"` or `"\r"`**.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Simulate an invalid number string returned
# from a script, which is "1234\n"
a='1234
'

if [ "$a" -gt 1233 ] ; then
    echo "number is bigger"
else
    echo "number is smaller"
fi
```

This will result in a script error `: integer expression expected` because `$a` contains a non-digit newline character `"\n"`. You have to remove this character using the instructions here: [How to remove carriage return from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345872/how-to-remove-carriage-return-from-a-string-in-bash)

So use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Simulate an invalid number string returned
# from a script, which is "1234\n"
a='1234
'

# Remove all new line, carriage return, tab characters
# from the string, to allow integer comparison
a="${a//[$'\t\r\n ']}"

if [ "$a" -gt 1233 ] ; then
    echo "number is bigger"
else
    echo "number is smaller"
fi
```

You can also use `set -xv` to debug your bash script and reveal these hidden characters. See https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bash-script-error-integer-expression-expected-934465/

Comment: Perfect! I got `93,` (with comma), that lead to this error.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using `-o` (or `-a`), it needs to be inside the brackets of the `test` command:

```
if [ "$age" -le "7" -o "$age" -ge " 65" ]
```

However, their use is deprecated, and you should use separate `test` commands joined by `||` (or `&&`) instead:

```
if [ "$age" -le "7" ] || [ "$age" -ge " 65" ]
```

Make sure the closing brackets are preceded with whitespace, as they are technically arguments to `[`, not simply syntax.

In `bash` and some other shells, you can use the superior `[[` expression as shown in [kamituel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19505322/1126841). The above will work in any POSIX-compliant shell.

Comment: Yes, looking at shebang, I assume OP's using `bash`. Good to point to POSIX solution, though, +1.

Answer (score 6):

```
./bilet.sh: line 6: [: 7]: integer expression expected
```

Be careful with `" "`

```
./bilet.sh: line 9: [: missing `]'
```

This is because you need to have space between brackets like:

```
if [ "$age" -le 7 ] -o [ "$age" -ge 65 ]
```

look: added space, and no `" "`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
If [ $a -lt 4 ] || [ $a -gt 64 ] ; then \n
     Something something \n
elif [ $a -gt 4 ] || [ $a -lt 64 ] ; then \n
     Something something \n
else \n
    Yes it works for me :) \n
```

Comment: It work for me dont use combian or dont use -o -a                  These are not working for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are just comparing numbers, I think there's no need to change syntax, just correct those lines, lines 6 and 9 brackets.

> Line 6 before: if [ "$age" -le **"7"]** -o [ "$age" -ge **" 65"** ]

After: `if [ "$age" -le "7" -o "$age" -ge "65" ]`

> Line 9 before: elif [ "$age" -gt "7"] -a [ "$age" -lt **"65"]**

After: `elif [ "$age" -gt "7" -a "$age" -lt "65" ]`