# Bash in if check integer

Tags: bash, shell

I have created a script in bash. I need to check if take 0 number then ignore this, but if take some value then I need to calculate based on the value given and print the result.

Here is an example:

```
if [ "$max_users_conn" -ne "0" ]; then
  let "percentage="$process_list"*100/"$max_users_conn""
  echo "$percentage"      
fi
```

However, when I run the code, I receive the following error:

> ./mysql_conn.sh: line 14: [: 0 10: integer expression expected
>   ./mysql_conn.sh: line 14: [: 0 10: integer expression expected
>   ./mysql_conn.sh: line 14: [: 5 5: integer expression expected 0 20

I also tried to run it like this:

```
if [ "$max_users_conn" != "0" ]; then
  let "percentage="$process_list"*100/"$max_users_conn""
  echo "$percentage"      
fi
```

But this gives a different error:

> ./mysql_conn.sh: line 15: let: percentage=4*100/0: division by 0
>   (error token is "0")
>   ./mysql_conn.sh: line 15: let: percentage=4*100/0: division by 0
>   (error token is "0")
>   0 0 20

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer expression expected error in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505227/integer-expression-expected-error-in-shell-script)

Comment: i try to do from this link, if [[ "$max_users_conn" -ne 0 ]]; then, but have the same error

Comment: I have checked with 
max_users_conn=5

if [ "$max_users_conn" -ne "0" ]; then
  process_list=10
  let "percentage="$process_list"*100/"$max_users_conn""
  echo "$percentage"
fi

and it worked with no problem. Did you try your script on different computer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash does not allow you math expressions like other languages do, you need to use the `$(( ... ))` operator for this. However, this operator gives you only operations base on integers if you supply integers: `echo $((2/4)) # => 0`. If you do not care about fractions, though, it will help you. If you need fractions, utilize `bc` like anubhava showed in his answer.

Additionally, you should check that `$max_users_conn` actually contains a value.

So, rewrite your snipped to look like this:

```
if [ -n "$max_users_conn" -a "$max_users_conn" -ne 0 ]; then
    percentage=$(( $process_list * 100 / $max_users_conn))
    echo "$percentage"      
fi
```

`test "$a" -ne 0` checks for numeric values, while `test "$a" != "$b"` checks for string equivalence.

Comment: have the next : ./mysql_conn.sh: line 14: [: 0
10: integer expression expected
./mysql_conn.sh: line 14: [: 0
10: integer expression expected
./mysql_conn.sh: line 14: [: 5
5: integer expression expected
./mysql_conn.sh: line 15: 0 * 100.0 / 5: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0 / 5")

Comment: Does `$max_users_conn` actually have a value? Have you checked? What about: `[ -n "$max_users_conn" -a "$max_users_conn" -ne 0 ]`? Additionally, my $(( )) operator contained a typo (100.0) from zsh, bash doesn't allow "100.0" but just "100". I corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh, does `$max_users_conn` contain a numeral at all?

Answer (score 0):

In BASH you can do:

```
if [[ $max_users_conn -ne 0 ]]; then
  percentage=$((process_list * 100 / max_users_conn))
  echo "$percentage"      
fi
```

but keep in mind that BASH doesn't support floating point maths and you will get an integer value returned.

---

To get decimal number returned use this `bc` command above.

```
percentage=$(bc -l <<< "scale=2; $process_list * 100 / max_users_conn")
```

Comment: If you need floating point arithmetic in a shell, zsh supports it (to a limited extent).

Comment: (1) you don't need quotes inside `[[ ... ]]` (2) `!=` is a string comparison, you want `-eq` instead.  See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for more details.

Comment: I think it should be `-ne` instead of `-eq`