# How to set Genymotion clock?

Tags: android, genymotion

I am having a big problem with figuring out how to get my local time in my app, and now I think my code is fine, it is just Genymotion has GMT time. How do I change the Genymotion clock to my local time zone? I tried to find help on their website, but found nothing. If anyone has experience with this, thanks in advance. I'm building an Android app in Eclipse (if that matters).

Comment: If the time drifts or becomes out of sync with the host computer, you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300999/set-the-date-from-a-shell-on-android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `Settings` device Choose `Date and Time`, then uncheck `Automatic time zone` and below select your `timezone`

Comment: That totally worked, thanks! I don't know why I didn't think to look there. I forget it emulates an actual phone. :)

Answer (score -1):

The answer of waki is totally right.

As I was troubled first, I would like to add the following detail.
Don't go to the Settings of Genymotion where there is no such option.
Choose and run one of your virtual devices and once started, go to the Settings at Android level.

Hope it helps... :)